# Display django form errors with js after ajax call

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views, django-forms

i have this signup form that works fine and saves the user correctly when there are no errors but when there are errors in the inputs like two password fields didn't match ,i couldn't display those errors that are sent to the front-end with `form.errors.as_json()`
so i need someone to guide me to display those errors with the js

**here is the form in my forms.py file:**

```
   class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Password', 'class': 'form-control mt-3','id':'password1'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm your password', 'class': 'form-control mt-3 mb-3','id':'password2'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("full_name", "email", "password1", "password2")
        widgets = {
            'full_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Full name', 'class': 'form-control mb-3','id':'full_name'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email', 'class': 'form-control','id':'email'}),
        }
```

**here the view of the form in my view.py:**

```
    signup_form = SignupForm()

    if request.is_ajax():
        signup_form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if signup_form.is_valid():
            signup_form.save()
            full_name = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
            email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account = authenticate(email=email, password=raw_password)
            login(request, account)
            return JsonResponse({"success" : True}, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False} ,signup_form.errors.as_json(),status=400)
```

**the ajax stuff in my javascript file**

```
  var $signupForm = $('#form-signup');
  $signupForm.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $signupData = $signupForm.serialize();
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:8000",
          method: 'POST',
          data: $signupData,
          success: function() {
            location.reload()
          },
          error: function () {
             // display the errors in a div or console.log them one by one
        },
        });
      });
```

with this code when the request fails that means it will run the error function when i added `console.log("error test")` to it i get error status code 500 and the errror is

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

on the django server terminal